# Accessing useState state inside a Cloudinary upload widget callback

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks, cloudinary

I'm using the [Cloudinary upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) inside a React component to upload images, and I'll like to run some code once those images are uploaded:

```js
const showWidget = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
const widget = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
      {
        cloudName,
        uploadPreset,
      },
      uploadCallback
    );
    widget.open();
  };
```

My issue is that the component's state (defined using `useState`) doesn't seem to be properly available inside `uploadCallback()`:

```js
const [ uploaded, setUploaded ] = useState([]);

const uploadCallback = (error, result) => {
  setUploaded([...uploaded, ...result.photos]);
}
```

The callback can trigger multiple times (once every time an image is finished uploading), and I wanted to add the uploaded image to the state each time, but inside the callback `uploaded` is always equal to its default value of `[]`, meaning each call to `setUploaded()` overwrites it instead of adding to it.

Is there a way to make this callback work with React state properly? Or does it boil down to how the callback is called by the widget library and there's not much I can do about it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: What if you call `showWidget` with `uploaded` and use that variable in `uploadCallback`?
`<button onClick={(e)=> showWidget(e, uploaded)}>Upload</button>`

Comment: Also, are you certain that you can use `uploadCallback:` like that? According to the docs it's just a callback function and there is no `uploadCallback` prop. Basically, you should get rid of `uploadCallback:` and just call the function there.

Comment: Just created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cherry-w5mti?file=/src/App.js). Replace `uploadPreset` and `cloudName` and try it. It works for me. You'll notice that the pictures array is logged each time is updated.

Comment: You're right I made a mistake when copy-pasting the code here. I'll also check out the CodeSandbox, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle this but here's what I ended up doing. The issue was that the component's local state only ever contained the last uploaded photo instead of containing all of them, so I decided to work with that and rename the variables:

```
const [ lastUploaded, setLastUploaded ] = useState([]);
```

And then have a separate `useEffect` hook to update another component (which is what I wanted to do in the first place anyway):

```
  // whenever local state changes, update global form state as well
  useEffect(() => {
      updateCurrentValues({ [path]: [...value, ...lastUploaded] });
  }, [lastUploaded]);
```

---

Note that another way to fix the issue was to replace `setLastUploaded([...lastUploaded, ...newPhotos])` by `setLastUploaded(lastUploaded => [...lastUploaded, ...newPhotos])`. I didn't actually know you could do that, even though I didn't end up using that in the end hopefully it can help others.